# Derivation of yamabe flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am reading papers about yamabe flow. I have a problem about how people derive it as a gradient flow.

Suppose we have $(M,g_0)$, $g(t)=u^{\frac{4}{n-2}}(t)g_0$ is another conformal metric. Let $R=R(t)$ be the scalar curvature and $s=\frac{\int_M Rd\mu}{\int_M d\mu}$ be the average scalar curvature at time $t$. I know many people use
$$u_t=(s-R)u$$
as yamabe flow. 
I want to view it as the gradient flow the following functional
$$E(u)=\frac{\int_M R\,d\mu}{V(t)^{\frac{n-2}{n}}}=\frac{\int_M \frac{4(n-1)}{n-2}|\nabla u|^2+R_0u^2\,d\mu_0}{\left(\int_M u^{\frac{2n}{n-2}}d\mu_0\right)^{\frac{n-2}{n}}}$$
where $V(t)$ is the volume.

By some lengthy calculation, the frechet derivative of $E$ is
$$\langle E'(u),v\rangle=\frac{2}{V(t)^{\frac{n-2}{n}}}\int_{M}(R-s)u^{-1}v\,d\mu$$
It seems that $E'(u)=\frac{2}{V(t)^{\frac{n-2}{n}}}(R-s)u^{-1}$ in the $L^2$ sense. So the $L^2$ gradient flow of this functional is 
$$u_t=-\frac{2}{V(t)^{\frac{n-2}{n}}}(R-s)u^{-1}$$
This is totally different from the yamabe flow as I mentioned. I expect we should have $u$ instead of $u^{-1}$ on the right hand side.

So what is the problem? how should I accommodate them?

Comment: I can't promise this will fix everything, but I think that your expression for $V(t)$ is wrong. The power of $u$ should be $\frac{2n}{n-2}$ rather than $\frac{2n}{n-1}$. (but maybe this was just a typo in your post).

Comment: Yes. I notice that. It is just a typo. Thank your very much.@OtisChodosh

Comment: The computation for $E'$ should not be that disgusting. So maybe you're taking a long route and somewhere there's a mistake? The computation of the gradient of the Yamabe functional can be found here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183553962, but its not so explicit. But it might help you get on the right track. If you can't figure it out, you should post your computation so that someone can help you out, otherwise its impossible to tell what went wrong.

Comment: As you do your calculation, keep track of how your equations transform if you rescale either $u$ or space by a constant factor. Both sides must scale the same. This will help you figure out where your error is.

Comment: I am pretty sure my calculation is right. I first saw the $E'$ on simon brendle's paper " a generalization of the yamabe flow for manifolds with boundary"page 629. I also checked by my hand. I think the problem may be we should not use $L^2$ gradient flow. For example, may be the $H^1$ gradient flow works. I don't know. Anyway thank you for your replying. @OtisChodosh

Comment: Yes your formula appears to be correct.

Comment: Could the difference be whether the gradient flow is with respect to the $L^2(g_0)$ metric or the $L^2(g)$ metric?

Comment: Here are my imprecise impressions: the Ricci flow is also not the gradient flow of the total scalar curvature. The exact flow used is mostly due to pragmatic reasons, namely you get an easier PDE to work with. In particular, it is the heat operator plus lower order terms.  The original motivation for the Ricci flow was not that it minimized any energy but just that it should head towards the solution of the time-independent solution. The Yamabe flow was studied only after Hamilton's work on Ricci flow, and it appears that the exact flow chosen was also for pragmatic reasons.

Comment: Also,  there is no reason to believe that the $L^2$ gradient flow is a good flow to use here both because you are not looking for the minimum of the energy and because the energy is not an "$L^2$" energy.

Comment: sounds reasonable. but I do want to have a way to explian why people study this kind of equation other than else.  @DeaneYang

Comment: That does not help either. $L^2(g_0)$ will also give you strange power of $u$. @MarkPeletier

Comment: When choosing what flow to use, the main thing you want is one for which you can obtain "nice" formulas and desired estimates. This usually means that you can prove curvature bounds using the maximum principle.

It should be emphasized that before Hamilton proved his spectacular theorem about positively curved 3-manifolds using the Ricci flow, nobody had studied geometric flows (except the harmonic map flow) in any setting, not even for curves. After that, the lesson learned was to find the simplest possible intrinsic flow that has curvature bounds using the maximum principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Yamabe flow is (up to a constant) the gradient flow of the Yamabe functional on the unit volume conformal class, as you expected. The comment by @Mark Peletier hints at your error: you aren't using the correct "inner product."

We briefly discuss the Ebin metric on the space of all metrics $Met$. Recall that $T_gMet = Sym^2 T^*M$. Then the Ebin/$L^2$ metric at $g$ is defined by
$$
g_E(h_1,h_2)|_g = \int_M tr(g^{-1}h_1g^{-1}h_2).
$$
See e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.0177v1.pdf for more information on the $L^2$ metric.
 Here, we are interested in the restriction of the Ebin/$L^2$ metric to the unit volume conformal class $[g]_1$. Now, the correct statement is

> The Yamabe flow is (up to a constant multiple) the (negative) Ebin/$L^2$-gradient flow of the Yamabe functional on $[g]_1$.

First, note that the tangent space to $[g]_1$ at $g$ is
$$
T_g[g]_1 = \left\{w g : \int_M w dV_g = 0\right\}.
$$
and the Ebin, or $L^2$ metric restricted to $[g]_1$ is given by
\begin{align*}
g_E(w_1g,w_2g)|_g & = \int_M tr(g^{-1} w_1 g g^{-1} w_2g)\\
& = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \int_M w_1 w_2 g^{ij}g_{j}^{k} g_{kl}g^l_i \, dV_g\\
& = n \int_M w_1 w_2 dV_g.
\end{align*}
So, up to a constant (which we'll ignore), $g_E|_{[g]_1}$ at $g$ is the $L^2$ inner product of the conformal factor. 
\begin{align*}
 \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} Y((1+tw)^{N-2}g) & = c \int_M (R_{g}-r_{g})wdV_g\\
& = g_E((R_g-r_g)g,wg)|_g
\end{align*}
This shows that (up to a constant),
$$
\nabla_{[g]_1} Y|_g = c_n(R_g-r_g)g,
$$
which is the Yamabe flow.

---

If you would rather think of the flow as a flow on the level of conformal factors, you may be a bit dissatisfied with the previous computation. So, lets do it again, where we imagine that $g$ is fixed, and the Yamabe flow at time $t$ is given by $v^{N-2}g$ (recall that $N = \frac{2n}{n-2}$). Then,
$$
T_{v^{N-2}g}[g]_1 = \left\{w v^{N-3} g : \int_M w v^{N-1} dV_g = 0\right\},
$$
so
\begin{align*}
g_E(w_1 v^{N-3} g,w_2 v^{N-3} g)|_{v^{N-2}g} & =  \int_M tr( v^{2-N} g^{-1} w_1 v^{N-3} g v^{2-N} g^{-1}w_2 v^{N-3} g ) v^N dV_g\\
& = n \int_M w_1 w_2 v^{4-2N+2N-6+N} dV_g\\
& = n \int w_1 w_2 v^{N-2} dV_g.
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
 \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} Y((v+tw)^{N-2}g) & = c\int_M (R_{v^{N-2}g} -r_{v^{N-2}g})v^{N-1}w dV_g\\
& = c\int_M (R_{v^{N-2}g} -r_{v^{N-2}g})v w v^{N-2} dV_g\\
& =c g_E((R_{v^{N-2}g} -r_{v^{N-2}g})v^{N-2}g,w v^{N-3}g)|_{v^{N-2}g}
\end{align*}
So,
$$
\nabla_{[g]_1} Y|_{v^{N-2}g} = (R_{v^{N-2}g} -r_{v^{N-2}g})v^{N-2}g,
$$
which of course is what we expected.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got impressed by you. @OtisChodosh